# How to handle Gson object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, gson

Am consuming third party **(java)Api** in my .Net application. It returns the following json 
**{"Image":[[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,52,10,37,-57,-27,-12,-27]]}**
object with byte array of pdf file they are using **Gson** for creating json objects.How to construct pdf from above byte array in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Gson is a library to write Json in Java. Once it's Json, the Gson part is irrelevant.

Just create a class with a `public byte[] Image` property in C# and deserialize the JSON into an instance of that class, then you can handle the image bytes any way you want.